# How to Access Copy Constructor from Driver

Tags: java, methods, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a driver which acts as my tester.

Here is the Driver:

```
public class CustomerTest {

    private static int customerCounter = 0;

    public static boolean test1(){
        System.out.println("Test1: create a customer");
        Customer c = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        customerCounter++;
        return c.getName().equals("Alice Smith") && customerCounter == c.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static boolean test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2: create two customers");
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Bob", "Simpson");
        customerCounter += 2;
        return c1.getName().equals("Alice Smith") && (customerCounter - 1) == c1.getCustomerID()
            && c2.getName().equals("Bob Simpson") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static boolean test4() {
        System.out.println("Test4: copy a customer");
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Bob", "Simpson");
        c1.copy(c2);
        customerCounter += 2;
        return c1.getName().equals("Bob Simpson") && (customerCounter) == c1.getCustomerID()
            && c2.getName().equals("Bob Simpson") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID()
            && c1 != c2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        //System.out.print("Test 1: ");
        result = test1() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);

        //System.out.print("Test 2: ");
        result = test2() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);

        //System.out.print("Test 4: ");
        result = test4() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);
```

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
public class Customer {

    public static final int MAX_ACCOUNTS = 5;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int customerID;
    private BankAccount[] accounts;
    private int numAccounts;
    private static int nextCustomerID = 1;

    //default constructor
    public Customer() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        customerID = nextCustomerID;
        accounts = null;
        numAccounts = 0;
        nextCustomerID++;

    }

    //Constructor sets name and initialized values
    //@param first is the first name
    //@param last is the last name
    public Customer (String first, String last)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.customerID = nextCustomerID;
        nextCustomerID++;



    }    

    public void copy (Customer copyFrom)
    {
        Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
        aCustomer.firstName = copyFrom.firstName;
        aCustomer.lastName = copyFrom.lastName;
        aCustomer.customerID = copyFrom.customerID;
        aCustomer.accounts = copyFrom.accounts;
        aCustomer.numAccounts = copyFrom.numAccounts;
    }
}
```

My copy constructor fails the driver test 4. I am not sure why because I copy everything that is invoked in the method.

Comment: test4 checks if (customerCounter) == c1.getCustomerID() and (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID(). Is this really what is supposed to be? That would mean that both customers have the same id, which does not sound right to me.

Answer (score 3):

As I see `copy()` is not a constructor in your case it's just a method of previously created object. If you want to create object and then fill it from another object you need to write something like this:

```
public void copy (Customer copyFrom) {
        this.firstName = copyFrom.firstName;
        this.lastName = copyFrom.lastName;
        this.customerID = copyFrom.customerID;
        this.accounts = copyFrom.accounts;
        this.numAccounts = copyFrom.numAccounts;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your method copy(Customer copyFrom) is not a constructor. A constructor returns a new customer object. What your copy does is creates an empty customer, assign field values and that's it. This new customer is gone from memory at the end of the method run. you can solve it by copy() returning the new customer like:

```
    public Customer copy(Customer copyFrom)...
```

Or write a real copy constructor:

```
    public Customer(Customer copyFrom)
    {
        this.firstName = copyFrom.firstName;
        this.lastName = copyFrom.lastName;
        this.customerID = copyFrom.customerID;
        this.accounts = copyFrom.accounts;
        this.numAccounts = copyFrom.numAccounts;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method copy (which isn't a constructor) you shouldn't use

```
Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
```

because you don't want to create a new instance of a Customer, you want to modify the current one. You should assign every attribute of the current instance (`this`) to the values of the instance `copyFrom`:

```
public void copy (Customer copyFrom)
    {
        this.firstName = copyFrom.firstName;
        this.lastName = copyFrom.lastName;
        this.customerID = copyFrom.customerID;
        this.accounts = copyFrom.accounts;
        this.numAccounts = copyFrom.numAccounts;
    }
```

The way you are doing it now, you could also decide to return `aCustomer` if you would like to create a new copy, but this would be a weird approach if you put the copy method inside the Customer class, it would be better to have it in another class (I called it CustomerHelper) as a static method:

```
public static Customer copy (Customer copyFrom)
{
    Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
    aCustomer.firstName = copyFrom.firstName;
    aCustomer.lastName = copyFrom.lastName;
    aCustomer.customerID = copyFrom.customerID;
    aCustomer.accounts = copyFrom.accounts;
    aCustomer.numAccounts = copyFrom.numAccounts;
    return aCustomer;
}
```

and then:

```
c1 = CustomerHelper.copy(c2);
```

Or, if you want to create a new instance which is a copy of the current instance, you could use a method like:

```
public Customer copy ()
    {
    Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
    aCustomer.firstName = this.firstName;
    aCustomer.lastName = this.lastName;
    aCustomer.customerID = this.customerID;
    aCustomer.accounts = this.accounts;
    aCustomer.numAccounts = this.numAccounts;
    return aCustomer;
    }
```

and use it:

```
c1=c2.copy()
```